# What does passing an entity class parameter to the createNativeQuery do?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've a simple find method in Hibernate:

```
@Override
public TblUser findByUsername(String username) {
    return (TblUser) entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE username = ?", TblUser.class)
            .setParameter(1, username)
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

What does passing an entity class parameter to the createNativeQuery method do? I can pass it or not and either way I've to cast the result from query using java. So what's the difference between the previous code snippet and this one:

```
@Override
public TblUser findByUsername(String username) {
    return (TblUser) entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE username = ?")
            .setParameter(1, username)
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

In the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String)) the only difference mentioned is that I should use the first method to delete and update. Is it the only difference between does two methods? To tell the programmer that it will return the result? Does it impact compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your First query return a **List of Object[] instead of the mapped entities**. 
 Each Object[] contains one record returned by the database. 
 We then need to iterate through the array, cast each Object to its specific type and map them to our domain model. 
 This creates lots of repetitive code and type casts

Your second query needs to **return all properties of the entity and the JPA implementation** (e.g. Hibernate) will try to map the returned columns to the entity properties based on their name and type. If that is successful, the EntityManager will return a list of fully initialized Author entities that are managed by the current persistence context. So the result is the same as if we had used a JPQL query, but we are not limited to the small feature set of JPQL.

for more detail see

http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-basics/